# Clear Formik field with initial value React

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, forms, formik

**CodeSandbox:**

> https://codesandbox.io/s/kind-fire-q4o45

**Question:**

Click on reset button and clear a field with value "initial value"

---

**Attempts:**

There are too many variants to reset form via:

1. `resetForm()`
2. `setFieldValue(<your_field_name>, '')`
3. `form.current.reset()`

But this list doesn't helpful when you have initial value in formik field.

---

**Snippet:**

```
import React from 'react'
import {Formik, Form, Field} from 'formik'

const Search = () => (
  <Formik onSubmit={({q}, {setSubmitting}) => {
    setSubmitting(false)
  }} initialValues={{q: 'initial value'}} render={({resetForm}) => (
    <Form>
      <Field name='q' />
      <button type="reset" onClick={() => resetForm()}>Reset</button> {/* <== Reset */}
    </Form>
  )}/>
)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're totally right - if you have some initial form state, the `resetForm` action will set the values to those initials. `setFieldValue` probably the only way to manually clear the field:

```
<button type="button" onClick={() => setFieldValue('q', '')}>
  Drop field
</button>
```

notice, `type='reset'` not need here...

In case when you need to drop multiple fields, take a look at this method:
`setValues({q: ''})`

Answer (score 3):

You can now reset formik by

```
formik.resetForm({
    values: { name: 'Custom initial values', email: '' },
});
```

https://formik.org/docs/migrating-v2#resetform

Comment: This resets all values, the OP wants to only reset one.

Answer (score 1):

yes when you reset form values it will reset it to default value
you can do the following

```
<Formik
  enableReinitialize
  onSubmit={(values, { setSubmitting }) => {
    values.q = '';
    setSubmitting(false);
  }}
  initialValues={{ q: "initial value" }}
  render={({ resetForm }) => (
    <Form>
      <Field name="q" />
      <button type="submit">
        Reset form
      </button>{" "}
      {/* <== Reset */}
    </Form>
  )}
/>
```

Hope it helps